# Stop IntelliJ from removing `` in angular 2, typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, intellij-idea

In Angular2 you write Block-HTML between a pair of ``. When I try to write a ` at the beginning or end of a word or together, IntelliJ (IDEA) removes one or both of those signs. How do I stop this? I am on MacOS.

Comment: Works fine for me. Which exact IDEA version? Can you give a specific example of what you typed where in what kind of file?

Comment: @Phil, can't recreate. Please provide a code sample plus exact steps to repeat

Comment: @lena it might be an issue with the input language or keyboard. I get no such weird behavior when I paste a `, only when I type it. I am using MacOS Sierra with German Input and latest IDEA

Comment: yes, this indeed can be related to keyboard layout. Related youtrack tickets: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21750, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-22768.